# I don't understand why object required error occurs every time in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a VBA project to determine if PE of a company is too high. I'm relatively inexperienced with vba, however, I cannot find anything wrong with my code, why does excel always return me an object required error? If anyone could help me, thank you!

```
Dim i As Long, pe As Long
Dim result As String

For i = 4 To 10
        pe = Sheet1.Range("C" & i).Value
        If pe >= 85 Then
            result = "High Destinction"
        ElseIf pe >= 75 Then
            result = "Destinction"
        ElseIf pe >= 55 Then
            result = "Credit"
        ElseIf pe >= 40 Then
            result = "Pass"
        Else
            result = "Fail"
        End If

        Sheet1.Range("D" & i).Value = result
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have a sheet with the codename of `Sheet1`?

Comment: Also, have you tried stepping through your code to see what line the error is occurring on?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look below:

[image]

**Refer to a worksheet using code name:**

`Sheet1.Range("D" & i).Value = result`

**Refer to a worksheet using worksheet name:**

`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i).Value = result`